# How does $y=\tan (x+y)$ differentiate?

Tags: calculus

So far, I have $y'=\sec^2(x+y)+\sec^2(x+y)(y')$.

How can this be simplified? The book has an explanation for a similar problem, but it's unclear how it leaps from one step to the next: It says $y=\sin(x+y)$ eventually diffs to $y'=\frac{\cos(x+y)}{1-\cos(x+y)}$. How can I get a similar form for the $\tan$ problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial derivative is wrong. Should look like this using chain rule:

$$y'=\sec^2(x+y)\cdot(1+y')$$

Simplifying:

$$y'-y'\sec^2(x+y)=\sec^2(x+y)$$

$$y'[1-\sec^2(x+y)]=\sec^2(x+y)$$

$$y'=\frac{\sec^2(x+y)}{1-\sec^2(x+y)}$$

$$y'=\frac{-\sec^2(x+y)}{\tan^2(x+y)}$$

$$y'=-\csc^2(x+y)$$

Answer (score 5):

So, in the problem from the book we have

$y'=\cos(x+y)(1+y')=\cos(x+y)+y'\cos(x+y)$ by the chain rule.

This leads to $y'(1-\cos(x+y))=\cos(x+y)\Rightarrow y'=\dfrac{\cos(x+y)}{1-\cos(x+y)}$

Note that the derivative of $y=\tan(x+y)$ is $y'=\sec^2(x+y)(1+y')$

So you can use a similar approach here also.